# Unpivot a DataFrame by month year elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table:

| Index | Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 136 | 137 | 169 |
| 2 | cde | 164 | 190 | 126 |
| 3 | edf | 130 | 179 | 136 |
| 4 | mno | 181 | 108 | 165 |

The Value columns correspond to Years 2021-2019. I want to duplicate each value for every month of the corresponding year. In other words, I want to restructure it into a DataFrame like this:

| Index | Name | Month | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 2 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 3 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 4 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 5 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 6 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 7 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 8 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 9 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 10 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 11 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 12 | 2021 | 136 |
| 1 | abc | 1 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 2 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 3 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 4 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 5 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 6 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 7 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 8 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 9 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 10 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 11 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 12 | 2020 | 137 |
| 1 | abc | 1 | 2019 | 169 |
| 1 | abc | 2 | 2019 | 169 |
| 1 | abc | 3 | 2019 | 169 |
| 1 | abc | 4 | 2019 | 169 |
| 1 | abc | 5 | 2019 | 169 |
| 1 | abc | 6 | 2019 | 169 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Since this is not a code writing service, what effort have you made at solving this yourself?

Comment: How are `LSQ`, `PSY` and `LSY` related to month ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion!  I changed column headings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with `melt` + `assign` and `explode` "Month":

```
out = (pd.melt(df.rename(columns={'Value1':2021, 'Value2':2020, 'Value3':2019}), 
               id_vars=['Index','Name'], value_vars=[2021, 2020, 2019], 
               var_name='Year', value_name='Value')
       .assign(Month=pd.Series([[*range(1,13)]])).ffill()
       .explode('Month')
       [['Index','Name','Month','Year','Value']]
       .sort_values(by=['Index','Name','Year'], ascending=[True, True, False])
       .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
     Index Name Month  Year  Value
0        1  abc     1  2021    136
1        1  abc     2  2021    136
2        1  abc     3  2021    136
3        1  abc     4  2021    136
4        1  abc     5  2021    136
..     ...  ...   ...   ...    ...
139      4  mno     8  2019    165
140      4  mno     9  2019    165
141      4  mno    10  2019    165
142      4  mno    11  2019    165
143      4  mno    12  2019    165

[144 rows x 5 columns]
```